# Azure SQL Database Backup Menu Not Available

Tags: sql, database, azure, azure-sql-database, database-backups

I'm trying to configure the automated backups for an Azure SQL Database.

On Microsoft's official website and pretty much anywhere I searched it states that I should have a ***"Manage Backups"*** option in the side menu of the SQL Server Resource page:

[image: Manage Backups Menu Option]

But ***I don't have this menu option***, and I can't find anything on why or how to enable it.

Microsoft Docs says that the option is available by default even on Standard instances. The instance I'm trying to configure is Premium.

This is the menu that I see:

[image: Azure SQL Menu - No Backups Option]
<sub>(source: [fleac.ro](https://fleac.ro/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/azure_sql_menu.png))</sub>

Answer (score 6):

Never mind, I was on the wrong Resource Page, was looking at the Database resource.

The ***Backup Menu*** is on the ***server's resource page***.

Comment: Thank you. I had the same issue and I thought I was going crazy when I couldn't find the backups section anywhere. Your comment helped me stay sane and go forward with my app.

Comment: Pfew... so I'm not the only one... :)  Glad it was helpful.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but you may be able to help me. I have the same issue, but when I go to the Server's resource page, I don't see the Manage Backups option. Any thoughts?

Comment: That's weird, it should be there, for any tier, as far as I know...